# How to perform nearest neighbor imputation in a time-series dataset?

Tags: pandas, nearest-neighbor

I have a panda-series of the form

```
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
5       NaN
6       NaN
7       NaN
8       0.0
9       1.0
10      NaN
11      NaN
12      NaN
13.     0.0
...
```

The values can either be 0.0 or 1.0. From my knowledge of the data however, the 0's come in groups. Meaning, the entries 0-8 should be 0, then entries 9-12 should all be 1's, and then 13+ will be 0's. Therefore, the best way to impute the NaN's would be to do some kind of nearest neighbor I believe. However, it should return a 0 or 1 obviously and not an average value. Please let me know of anyway to do this!

Comment: `series.ffill().bfill()`.

Comment: Works fantastic!